# Why MySQL index merge is not used?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Using the table stucture as in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/572f9/2 ,

1. Why the used index is only company_id and created index is not used?
2. Why on my machine, using the exact same table structure and query, in the POSSIBLE_KEYS column appears only company_id? MySQL version: 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1-log (Ubuntu)

Comment: What is the collation of your database and your client connection? I need this info because I think you run into a bug present in 5.5.

Comment: @FloDoe  
`>show variables like '%collation%';

+----------------------+-----------------+

| Variable_name        | Value           |

+----------------------+-----------------+

| collation_connection | utf8_unicode_ci |

| collation_database   | utf8_unicode_ci |

| collation_server     | utf8_unicode_ci |

+----------------------+-----------------+

3 rows in set (0.00 sec)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure you run in a bug which is present in 5.5 and fixed with 5.6. Here index on datetime colums are not used when a collation different to `utf8_general_ci` is used. See following links: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68942 and http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64998.

This is also the case for combined indexes which have a datetime value on the left most part. So a possible solution would be creation of an combined index which doesn´t start with datetime. Please see below a sample testing session using your example from above.

So in your case I would try to go for a combined index as Vatev suggested, but keep in mind not to start it with the datetime column. If this index is used, it will depend on the optimizer. But it will be listed as possible key. A diferent solution would be to use either 5.1.xx or 5.6 (had only the chance to verify against 5.6.12, but bug report states it doesnt happen in 5.1.60).

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "version";
+---------------+------------+
| Variable_name | Value      |
+---------------+------------+
| version       | 5.5.28-log |
+---------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like '%collation%';
+----------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value             |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci   |
| collation_database   | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci |
+----------------------+-------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE tbl (
    ->   id int(11) not null auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   user_id int(11) not null,
    ->   company_id int (11) NOT NULL,
    ->   created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ->   oid int(11) NOT NULL,
    ->   did varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    ->   status int(11) NOT NULL,
    ->   KEY company_id (company_id),
    ->   KEY user_id (user_id),
    ->   KEY created (created),
    ->   KEY operator_id (oid),
    ->   KEY did (did)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created, '%M %d, %Y') as date, count(id) as num_accepted FROM tbl WHERE created BETWEEN '2013-06-29' AND '2013-07-30' AND company_id = 20 AND (status in (2,5))  GROUP BY `date` ORDER BY created ASC;
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------+------------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys      | key        | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------+------------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tbl   | ref  | company_id,created | company_id | 4       | const |    1 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------+------------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created, '%M %d, %Y') as date, count(id) as num_accepted FROM tbl WHERE created BETWEEN '2013-06-29' AND '2013-07-30' AND company_id = 20 AND (status in (2,5))  GROUP BY `date` ORDER BY created ASC;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tbl   | ref  | company_id    | company_id | 4       | const |    1 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL determines which index to use at run time depending on statistics it keeps on the tables. It is normal to choose different query plans depending on the data.

For this query it will have to use an intersect index merge, which is not very efficient, and it decided (correctly or not) not to do it.

It will be much better if you create an index on `(company_id,status,created)`. That way it will be able to filter the results directly from the index.

I can't think of a reason why only one of the keys would appear as possible (assuming you really have both keys).